# Similar jQuery functions not firing keyup() more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a few JavaScript functions that all look similar to me. but behave differently to how I want them to.

I would like another element to be updated with some text when the value of the input has been evaluated. However for code re-useability I would like to pass the element to be updated to the function, but when I do this the `keyup()` event will not fire when text is typed into the input box.

**Why is this?**

Here is the one that works, but I have so specify the element to be updated explicitly.

***Keyup Working***

```
$(function(){ 
     $("#form1").keyup(function(){
         var val = $(this).val();
         if(val.length < 5){
             $("#inputFeedback").html("Less then 5 chars");
         }else{
             $("#inputFeedback").html("More then 5 Chars!");
     }
});
```

Here is what I would like to do but the `keyup()` event  will not work on.

***Keyup Not working***

```
var validate = function(feedback){
   var val = $(this).val();
   if(val.length < 5){
       $(feedback).html("Less then 5 chars");
   }else{
       $(feedback).html("More then 5 Chars!");
   }
}


$(function(){
    $("#form1").keyup(validate($("#inputFeedback")));
});
```

***Note:** I have also tried as arguments `$(this)` and `"#inputfeedback"` to no avail!*

I have also tried to use classical JavaScript `function foo(bar){ ... }` type functions but this has the same effect as the last example above.

I am sure it is something I am not doing right or understanding here but after a good few hours of searching and reading I can't find anything to help me with this one!

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new syntax for $(document).ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can't do callbacks like that:

http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Wrong

Comment: Thanks, I thought It was actually something like there was an extra parameter I was missing but the explanation actually makes more sense. I feel rather stupid now!!

Comment: Don't feel too bad. It is on the first page of jquery's tutorial, but then again, it's kind of counter-intuitive.

Comment: Ugh!  This makes so much since now that I've seen it.  Guess I ought to take a read-through of that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
var validate = function(feedback){
  var val = $(this).val();

  if(val.length < 5){
    $(feedback).html("Less then 5 chars");
  }else{
    $(feedback).html("More then 5 Chars!");
  }
}


$(function(){
  $("#form1").keyup(function(){
    validate.call(this, '#inputFeedback');
  });
});
```

or

```
var validate = function(feedback){
  return function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val.length < 5){
      $(feedback).html("Less then 5 chars");
    }else{
      $(feedback).html("More then 5 Chars!");
    }
  }
}


$(function(){
  $("#form1").keyup(validate('#inputFeedback'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the working examples. I would +1 if I could. The only reason I didn't pick yours as the answer was because I didn't find out where I was going wrong. Thanks Anyway!

Comment: In your question code not working because keyup function need a reference to function, that will be invoked when event were triggered but you immediately invoke this function handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it this way:

```
var feedback=$("#inputFeedback");
$("#form1").keyup(validate(feedback));
```